# Dashboard to compare different companies with different currencies

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with multiple companies.

| Shop | Currency |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | € |
| S2 | € |
| S3 | kr |
| S4 | £ |
| S5 | € |

And a table with the exchange rate

| Currency | Exchange rate |
| --- | --- |
| € | 1.00000000000 |
| £ | 1.17100000000 |
| kr | 0.09730000000 |

When using a formula like this

`YearRevenue = SUM(Shop[Revenue]) * SUM(Currency[Exchange rate])`

Logically what it now does is add all revenues in 1 pile and add all the conversions rate in 1 pile.

So what happens is all the revenue will be multiplied by 2.2683

I want this to be calculated for each shop individually and sum up at the end.

I think I have 2 options:

1. Is to add a column with the calculated revenue based on the exchange rate so I don't have to use a formula.
2. A formula which I have no idea on how to aproach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SUMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax), your expression would be like this:

```
YearRevenue = SUMX(Shop,Shop[Revnue]*RELATED('Currency'[Exchange rate]))
```

Make sure that your 2 tables are linked with a many to one relationship on `Currency` column.

Comment: This worked for me! This looks so logical, I need to take a closer look into SUMX and the RELATED part.